# How do I type check variables and functions passed through context in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I want to type check using prop-types for variables and functions coming from context, How do i do it, I dont find anything related to it.

I found GitHub issue related to it, But its confusing and i didn't get it well.

Below is my code

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { appContext} from 'store/store';

const Drawer = ({isOpen, onCloseDrawer}) => {
      let context = useContext(appContext)
      let { user, userInfo} = context.state;

      return <div>Some data</div>
}
```

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: No, I am not using typescript.

Comment: Is there anyone ?